# Font available in MS Word is missing from the system fonts folder

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, fonts

(Google only provides solutions for the opposite problem)

In Microsoft Word (Desktop) I have fonts like for example "Bierstadt".
When I look in C:\Windows\Fonts\ that font is not there. I even searched the entire drive.

Anyone know why, and where I can find it?

Comment: Apparently, they're "cloud" fonts, https://office-watch.com/2021/check-out-the-five-new-fonts-in-microsoft-365/ , in line with Microsoft wanting your identity and your work to be cloud based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are "cloud fonts", which Microsoft downloads to your computer on demand. They are stored in the folder `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Publishers\8wekyb3d8bbwe\Fonts\FontCache\4\CloudFonts\`, and they have obfuscated names like `22829156475.ttf`.

I am not certain of the license issues, but it would be easy enough to rename them (using the list at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cloud-fonts-in-office-f7b009fe-037f-45ed-a556-b5fe6ede6adb as a guide), then right-click and "Install for all users". This would put them in the `Fonts` folder, and make them available system-wide.

Oh, that Microsoft page says "Cloud fonts are only available to Microsoft 365 subscribers". Not true, they are also available in the Mail app in plain Windows 10 (start to compose the body of a message, and start picking fonts from the drop-down; they're downloaded automatically).